# Number of solutions to a modular equation of a specific form

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I struggle with this Exercise, or at least the part where one should prove how many solutions there are. Simply inserting f=0 contradicts the suggested number of solutions.

> Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $e\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $e\gt 1$.  Let $a$ be an integer of the form $a = p^f b$, where $0\le f \lt e$ and $p \not \mid b$.  Consider the integer solutions $z$ to the congruence $z^2 \equiv a \mod{p^e}$.  Show that a solution exists if and only if $f$ is even and $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, in which case there are exactly $2p^f$ distinct solutions modulo $p^e$.

At first I tried to subtract the right hand side and considered the conjugate. Then I factored out $p^{f/2}$, but in the end it didn't work out.

Problem source:
A Computational Introduction to Number Theory and Algebra (Second edition), by Victor Shoup.

Exercise number 2.41

I missunderstood the question, got it know.

Comment: What's the equation?????

Comment: If you do not put the text of your question here, a future searcher will not find it.

Comment: I have edited in the mathematical expressions of the Exercise (see [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$).  You should add to your Question the source of the Exercise (book title and author, at a minimum), and you should include your work on showing that solutions exist even if you were not able to establish the exact count of solutions.

Comment: Thanks, hardmath. The problem in text form:

p is an odd prime and e an integer greater than 1. Let a be an integer of the form a=b*p^f, where 0<=f<e and p not dividing b. Consider the integer solutions to the congruence z^2=a(mod p^e).

Show that a solution exist if and only if f is even and b a quadratic residue modulo p, in which case there are exactly 2p^f distinct solutions modulo p^3.

Comment: The problem for me, is that I find the answer (p^(e-1))(p-1) to be the correct one. Am I wrong with this?